# Changing domain of all requests in postman workspace

Tags: api, collections, postman, workspace

We are developing a rest API and giving it to many customers. For testing purpose for each customer we create a new workspace in postman and add some collections contains of requests to that. Each customer has its own domain name obviously so each workspace contains request with unique domain address and also unique x-api-key header.
When we release our API for new customer, we must add a new workspace with all requests. using export/import collection we can add request from old workspaces very fast but changing domain name and x-api-key header one by one for each request in new workspace  is exhausting!
Is there any way in postman to do such work automatically?

Comment: Are you not using `{{...}}` variables so you're only changing it in a single place?

Comment: May you explain more or provide a link?

Comment: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/managing-environments/